# I got a problem when I try to composer init command

Tags: php, composer-php

[image]

reason for the above problem is vendor name. It has a space between my names.
Is there any way to solve this problem??

[image]
I tried to change my user folder name but some reasons It was not worked.
Is there any way to solve this problem without changing my name??

Comment: Once you're prompted for package-name, you can enter the name manually without spaces: `RuchiraLakmal` and the error would be gone.

Comment: no caps @SachinBahukhandi ;)

Comment: Posting this as an answer for anyone who stumbles around this.

Comment: What do you mean by "above problem"? Please add all clarification **in text form**, not hidden in screenshots

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anyone stumbles around this, you could provide the vendor name yourself:

While running `composer init`, just enter the Package Name manually:

In this case, just enter: `ruchiralakmal` and as [Leroy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2525872/leroy) pointed.